# javascript increment (more than ++) style attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes, styles, increment

I'm having some trouble in moving a `div` tag over with `onclick`. I can get it to move once but then I don't know how to get the new variable and add to it again.

NO jquery please and I'm not really worried about cross platforms at the moment

```
function addToMargin()  {

        var marginleft = 20;
        document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.marginLeft = marginleft + "px";
}

#show-sessions  {
        margin-left:10px;
        width:200px;
        overflow:hidden;
}
```

I tried setting a global variable to store the number in but then it became a `NaN`

any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: I hope you understand that the margin will be 20 and not 30 because javascript canot read the css style like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The golobal variable thing wasn't a bad idea, try something like this:

```
var margin = 20;
function addToMargin()  {
        margin ++; //or += value
        document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
}
```

I'd also probably provide the initial margin as an inline style, just in case...

Comment: Thanks Gabor this is working for me maybe because I understand it, I haven't been able to get the answer everyone likes to work for me.

Comment: its a valid and simple answer, but i dont think its a good idea to set a global variable just for a single function. http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/

Comment: I switched it around for another button to go the other way so its for two functions ^^

Answer (score 5):

```
function addToMargin()  {  
        var marginleft 
            = parseInt(document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.marginLeft) + 20;
        document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.marginLeft = marginleft + "px";
}
```

Comment: don't forget to parse float the style, because as far as i can recall it comes back with a px tacked on there.

Comment: @hhamilton: `parseInt` will handle the `px`.

Comment: @Diodeus your "answer" was a tip not the actual solution. i didnt downvoted btw

Comment: @hhamilton yes `parseInt` will stop at any non numeric caracter

Comment: clientLeft is an option too and it returns value not string

Comment: Answer was edited to include parsing, and parse int is a good way to go here, but sometimes margins are specified in floating point values. It all depends on what hobbywebsite wants.

Comment: wow thanks for all the help guys... this is returning NaN for me. I'm in chrome if that tells you anything...

Comment: @hobbywebsite: The `element.style.marginLeft` won't pick up styles from your stylesheet. You will need to start of by assigning a value like `"20px"`, and from there you can increment it.

Comment: in the style or the js? Sorry Majid I'm going to have to go with the global answer since it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addToMargin(value)  {
    var element = document.getElementById("show-sessions");
    var marginleft = parseInt(element.style.marginLeft.replace('px', ''));
    element.style.marginLeft = (marginleft + value) + "px";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `element.style.marginLeft` in the last line?

Comment: +1 but the `.replace()` isn't really needed. Doesn't hurt of course.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution for future reference and research:

```
function addToLeft()  {  
    var left 
        = document.getElementById("show-sessions").clientLeft + 20;
    document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.Left = left + "px";
```

}

note1: this changes the left position, not the marginleft.

note2: the returning value is int not string.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable marginLeft will remain 20 and that's why it's moving once. Are you not perhaps trying to achieve something like this:

```
var marginLeft = 20;
var tot = document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.marginLeft;
document.getElementById("show-sessions").style.marginLeft = (tot + marginLeft) + "px"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window.getComputedStyle()` method. And maybe make a reusable function for better abstraction. Something like:

```
function move(el, val) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    el.style.marginLeft = parseInt(style.marginLeft) + val + "px";
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("show-sessions").onclick = function (e) {
        move(this, 20);
    };
};
```

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvUn9/2/).